# Remove Cisco AnyConnect obsolete VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I have an obsolete VPN that Cisco AnyConnect keeps trying to connect to. I can't find the file that this is stored in so I can remove it.

Can anyone lead me to where or how this can be removed permanently.

Comment: Can you please help us with the screenshot?

Comment: Did you set preference to automatically establish VPN when AnyConnect UI is launched ?

Comment: @Mahesh No I turned it off... what benefit will that bring?

Comment: The preference will automatically initiate a VPN connection when UI is launched. Remove invalid host entries from AnyConnect profile. Check [this thread](http://www.tunnelsup.com/locating-the-cisco-anyconnect-profiles) in locating VPN profiles on your OS.